# how to search for a file in directory and sub directories basing on the file name in ssis

Tags: sql, ssis

How can we search for a particular file in  sub folders basing on the file name.
 I have multiple sub folders and the file which i am looking for may present in the sub folder level or it may be present in sub folders under the present sub folder. 
       can any of you guys help me in this

Comment: Your edit still doesn't help me understand your needs. Perhaps a concrete example will help illuminate the issue

Answer (score 2):

The [Foreach Loop Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141724.aspx) is a powerful construct in your SSIS toolbox. If you use the File Enumerator, which is the default, you can specify

- Where to start,
- What to look for
- How to retrieve the location
- Search subfolders

[image]

### What to look for

Currently displayed as `*.txt` indicates that all files ending in `.txt` are an acceptable match. As @lamak has commented, if you have a requirement to only find files that start with something, then you would change the value to `MyFilePrefix*.txt` That would match files files

- C:\ssisdata\Operations\Input\MyFilePrefix_20130618.txt
- C:\ssisdata\Operations\Input\SubFolder\MyFilePrefix_20130618.txt
- C:\ssisdata\Operations\Input\SubFolder\SubSubfolder\MyFilePrefix.txt

while excluding things such as

- C:\ssisdata\Operations\MyFilePrefix_20130618.txt
- C:\ssisdata\Operations\Input\SubFolder\YourFilePrefix_20130618.txt
- C:\ssisdata\Operations\Input\SubFolder\SubSubfolder\MyFilePrefi.txt

Comment: well I tried this but it didn't worked for me because in this example it will search  for .txt files in input and the sub folders in input. In my scenario I have files like       in the Operations folder i have multiple sub folders again like Input, output then i may have files or again i may have some more sub folders and contain files. i tried For each loop but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: That still doesn't compute. Please edit your question to call out the specific scenario you are attempting to address, comments are woefully inadequate.

Comment: @Newtostackoverflow Then why are you looking on the `Input` folder?, choose the right folder for doing the loop. And you can still use wildcards on the file name, instead of `*.txt` you can use `SomePrefix*.txt` or something like that